# Intersection of a function and a line

Tags: c++, function, math, intersection

I am trying to find a way to find the first point of intersection between a function and a line. I don't know if it is even possible though.

The idea is, that I have a line segment, and then I have a box that is rotating while it moves through 2space. I have made these two functions that represent the position of one of the vertices of the box as it moves through 2space. Basically, the functions represent the rotation of a point, or vertex of the box that is moving through 2space linearly.

```
float F_X(float time) // X coordinate of the vertex at a certain time
{
    return VertX * COS(Degrees * time)
         - VertY * SIN(Degrees * time)
         + time * Velocity;
}
float F_Y(float time) // Y coordinate of the vertex at a certain time
{
    return VertX * SIN(Degrees * time)
         + VertY * COS(Degrees * time)
         + time * 0;// no velocity on y for this example
}
float F_Center(float time) // center position of the box along it's path
{
    return (time * Velocity);
}
```

so my question is, given the starting and ending positoni of the box, and it's angular velocity, is it possible to find the first point of intersection of the orbiting vertex and a given line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Represent the line with the equation `A*x+B*y=C`, such that if it passes through `(x1,y1)` and `(x2,y2)` then the equation is `x*(y2-y1)+y*(x1-x2)=x1*y2-x2*y1`.

2) The signed distance of any point `(xp,yp)` to the line is :

```
d = (A*xp+B*yp-C)/sqrt(A*A+B*B)
```

or

```
d=( yp*(x2-x1)-xp*(y2-y1)+x1*y2-x2*y1 )/sqrt((x2-x1)^2+(y2-y1)^2)
```

When `d` switches sign then the point just crossed the line

3) For small time increment `Dt` the point position changes by

```
(Dxp,Dyp)=Dt*(Vx+Omg*(Vy*t-yp),Vy+Omg*(xp-Vx*t))
```

where `Omg` is the rotational velocity (in your case `Omg=Degrees`), `(Vx,Vy)` is the center velocity (in our case `(Velocity,0)`) and `t` is time.

4) Find the distance `d1` at time `t1`, and estimate the distance `d2` a small time after at `t2`. In order to make the distance zero in between a time step `Dtc` from `t1` fit a line through the two distance estimates

```
d_est = d1 + (d2-d1)*Dtc/(t2-t1)
```

and solve `d_est=0` for `Dtc = d1*(t2-t1)/(d1-d2)`.

Of course instead of estimating the next position, you can take the step and measure it, and then go back in time to the point of intersection. Regardless, I have given you the tools to solve this numerically.

Comment: You'll need to ensure the box isn't moving so quickly that it can cross the line and back again between evaluations of these functions. It's a classic physics library problem.

Comment: As I said in step 3) "For a small time increment". Thats why I said to estimate where `d2` is in 4) which does not exhibit any double crossings (it is a linear motion estimation). It all hinges in small time increments in relation to `Velocity` and `Omg*BoxSize`.

Comment: I don't understand how the above solution would fit, because the problem I have explained intersects a line with a curve, but all your eqns seem to be linear

Comment: @Nick. There is no analytical solution. The best you can do is assume linear behavior for small time steps and check often for collisions.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I was afraid that was the case. I was hoping to find a way to do this in one possibly expensive, but accurate iteration. What I am really looking for is a solution to collision detection that is 100% tunnel proof and accurate, hence the attempt at tracing the exact path of the orbiting vertex. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: You will have to sample often and detect when the vertex is on the far side of the line.

You haven't said anything about the orientation of the line, but we can (Without Loss Of Generality) rotate the whole problem to put the line someplace convenient, like the Y axis. We can also neglect any motion of the box, or of the vertex, that is parallel to the line. So the whole thing reduces to:

X = R cos(omega * time) + V<sub>x</sub> * time + X<sub>0</sub>

where X<sub>0</sub> is the initial position of the vertex and R is its distance from the center of the box (R<sup>2</sup> = VertX<sup>2</sup> + VertY<sup>2</sup>). There is no tidy analytical way to solve this equation (that is, to find a time when X=0), so you simply have to calculate it for many times and pick the first one for which X>0 (assuming that you started out with X<sub>0</sub> < 0).

Comment: "I have a line *segment*" (emphasis added). So I think we might not be able to ignore motion parallel to the line, although we could find all intersections with the line first, then filter which ones occur within the line segment. If the box's component of velocity perpendicular to the line is non-0 there are only finitely many intersections, and if it is 0 then the equation simplifies, so either way I don't think it's much extra work to account for the difference between line and segment.

Comment: Also, is there really no analytic solution to `cos(A*t) + Bt + C = 0`? And even if there isn't, is sampling the best numeric method? No way we can use Newton-Raphson or whatever? We can at least binary chop within a region where the first derivative of the function doesn't cross 0.

Comment: @Steve Jessop: the OP said "line segment" once and "line" twice; I thought of asking for clarification, but decided to solve the simple part of the problem first. Yes, there are ways to sample cleverly, to eliminate large domains from the search, but I think it's better to get the crude solution working first.